# New Site Column Types in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm looking for the definitive list of Site Column Types in SharePoint 2010.

For example Type="Text", Type="Boolean".

In SQL these would be the data types.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete list found at the bottom of this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx

Seems like Integer is now a valid type. Pretty cool!